# Are session variables hidden from the user in MeteorJS?

Tags: meteor

Just wondering, should we be using Meteor's sessions on the assumption that in production, the user has read and/or write access to them at all times or is it like encrypted similar to ASP.NET View States?

Just want to know if I have to design / test my application for the user modifying them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session variables are *not* hidden.  Anyone can view and change the values.

Comment: Right. Be sure to check() arguments to Meteor.publish functions.

Comment: @DonnyWinston : as an additional question, does this mean that all code unless it's inside the "IsServer" can be viewed and modified by the user?

Comment: All code not in the server/ directory is sent to the client, albeit minified in production and thus obfuscated somewhat. From there, it's like any web app in that a client can reassign global identifiers from the console. Note that "var" declares a variable in Meteor with scope restricted to its file, not with global scope.