# How do I use global variables in myapp.js file if I do not want to use Session variables?

Tags: meteor

I do not want to use Session because of security issues. What is the followed practice of using global variables in Meteor apps. They are not necessarily Handlebars helpers btw.

Comment: What exactly is the variable? What are the security concerns about it?

Comment: Well for one, I want to restrict the usage of the variable from the user. This tells me that I cannot do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448923/are-session-variables-hidden-from-the-user-in-meteorjs

Comment: They are state control variables in my web-app.

Comment: Yeah, the only place you can prevent the user from making modifications to any kind of data is on the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume you have some secret information called `superSecretKey`.

Stuffing it into a global variable (`window.superSecretKey`) is clearly no more secure than `Session.get('superSecretKey')`. A slightly better way to do this is to use methods (only because it doesn't keep the variable stored on the client). For example:

#### server

```
Meteor.methods({
  getSuperSecretKey: function() {
    return 'abc123';
  }
});
```

#### client

```
Meteor.call('getSuperSecretKey', function(err, key) {
  // do something useful with key
});
```

Beyond that, the more you can do on the server without exposing `superSecretKey`, the better. For example, let's say you needed to delete a file via a REST interface which required `superSecretKey`. You *could* pass the key and have the client remove the file, but a more secure solution would be to have the server take care of everything for you.